# Incorrectly handle the quantity button for variable product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, product-variations

I added quantity plus, minus button for both simple product and variable product. There correctly handled and correctly work for simple product, but did not correctly get the quantity for variable product for example: I set the quantity to ‘3’, the quantity did not get ‘3’, there only one get the variable product in the cart. Here is the code below

```
/**
 * Display QTY Input before add to cart link.
 */
function custom_wc_template_loop_quantity_input() {
    // Global Product.
    global $product;

    // Check if the product is not null, is purchasable, is in stock, and not sold individually.
    if ( $product && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        if ( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
            // For simple products.
            woocommerce_quantity_input(
                array(
                    'min_value' => 1,
                    'max_value' => $product->backorders_allowed() ? '' : $product->get_stock_quantity(),
                )
            );
        } elseif ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            // For variable products.
            woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart();
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_wc_template_loop_quantity_input', 9 );

/**
 * Add JS script in <head/> tag.
 */
function custom_wc_add_qty_change_script() {
    ?>
    <script>
        (function ($) {
            $(document).on("change", "li.product .quantity input.qty", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var add_to_cart_button = $(this).closest("li.product").find("a.add_to_cart_button");
                // For AJAX add-to-cart actions.
                add_to_cart_button.attr("data-quantity", $(this).val());
                // For non-AJAX add-to-cart actions.
                add_to_cart_button.attr("href", "?add-to-cart=" + add_to_cart_button.attr("data-product_id") + "&quantity=" + $(this).val());
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_wc_add_qty_change_script', 20 );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0muK.png)

Comment: I just tested this code snippet with the StoreFront theme and the added quantity is updated in the cart when I tried adding it from the shop page. Are you having the issue with the increment button or added quantity is not reflected in the cart.?

Comment: The code work well for simple product but did not work for variable product. For example; I set the quantity '2' of variable product and click the 'Add to cart' button, there did not get '2' only one get the quantity.

Comment: Please check by changing the theme ( move the code snippet as well ) - It's working fine in Storefront